# Moving files to a folder google drive/sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am new to google and am trying to create spreadsheets and then move it to a specific folder.

On the "Synthése Mag" sheet I have all the name I gave to the files.

The spreadsheet are successfully created, however, when I try to move it, the following message appear :

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property
> getFolderById on object DriveApp.

My code is the following :

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Synthése mag'), true);
  for(var i=2;i<4;i++){
   var mag = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Synthése mag').getRange(i,2).getValue ();
  
   var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(mag);
Logger.log(ssNew.getUrl());
var newmag = DriveApp.getFilesByName(mag)
DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID").addFile(newmag)
  
};

}
```

Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The issue in the code is that [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) does not return a [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) but a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator). You want to get a `file` object and therefore you can use [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)) and pass the id of the file.
- There is no need to activate a sheet and redefine the sheet inside the `for` loop.
- Get all the values before the loop so you don't call `getRange/getValue` iteratively

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const mag = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Synthése mag');
  const names = mag.getRange('B2:B3').getValues().flat();
  names.forEach(nm=>{
    let ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(nm);
    let ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ssNew.getId());
    DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID").addFile(ssFile)
  })
};
```